# How to use getPopup() in manifest 3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am using

> chrome.action.setPopup({popup: 'popup.html'})

but I also want to get used of getPopup function, but documentation is not very clear.

What I found
is

> chrome.action.getPopup(
> details: TabDetails,
> callback?: function,)

I am not very experienced with JS, but compared with setPop function

> chrome.action.setPopup(
> details: object,
> callback?: function,
> )

I know I have to use a callback function as second parameter and for first parmeter details TabDetails which is not very clear what means but found this
[image]

So the question is how to correct use getPopup to retrieve the value of popup html ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the call for getPopup

```
chrome.action.getPopup({}, function(popupUrl) {
    alert(`"${popupUrl}"`);
});
```